# Replacing regex with new regex

Tags: python, regex

Say I have

"a acrobat jumped over an bridge"

and I want to change this to

"an acrobat jumped over a bridge".

Right now, I'm using

`lyrics = re.sub(r" a (a|e|i|o|u|y){1}([a-z]+|[A-Z]+)", r" an (a|e|i|o|u|y){1}([a-z]+|[A-Z]+)", lyrics)`

and the resulting string doesn't replace in the way I'd hope it would, as expected. How else can I do this?

To clarify, I want to be able to generalize this for every case, not just the example I used above.

Comment: could you add some more detail about what your regex is supposed to replace? Right now it sounds like you want to make "a" into "an" and "an" into "a", but I'm guessing from the look of your current regex that you're trying to do a little more than that?

Comment: Second argument `re.sub` get `string`, not `regexp`. You can't replace it by `re.sub`.

Comment: @alexanderbird apologies.. I used the wrong regex expression

Comment: What do you mean by "for every case"? You're not asking for grammar checking for all english grammar rules, are you? Or do you mean any sentence which has incorrect use of "an" or "a"?

Comment: @alexanderbird I mean the latter.. to be able to replace a word starting with a vowel preceded by "a" to "an"

Comment: Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: Note that the a/an rule is based on the sound of the letter, not the letter itself, for instance if one was using "Xtension" as a proper name/brand name/something, you "an Xtension" would be the proper text.

Comment: Since it wasn't mentioned, your problem is that the original text "acrobat..." is not included in the replacement. You need a [backreference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), or a capture method that does not capture the following word (as in the accepted answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to English grammar, `an` comes before a word that starts with a vowel. For that you can use this:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\ba\b(?=\s+[aeiouAEIOU])', 'an', "a acrobat jumped over a bridge")
'an acrobat jumped over a bridge'
>>> re.sub(r'\ba\b(?=\s+[aeiouAEIOU])', 'an', "a elephant")
'an elephant'
>>>
```

Notice, `a` before `acorbat` has been changed to `an`, whereas `a` before bridge has not been changed. Also the `a` before `elephant` has been changed to `an`, hence the above regex is generalized and works for all words.

Here we are using:  `'\ba\b(?=\s+[aeiouAEIOU])'`

`\ba\b` tries to match a literal `a` with word boundary on either sides
`(?=\s+[aeioudAEIOU])` ensures positive lookahead of vowel space and vowel char

To replace all `a` with `an` you can use this:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\ba\b', 'an', "a bridge")
'an bridge'
```

Comment: That's good, but how can I make the regex generalizable? To make it work for every word combinations

Comment: @dbalagula23 the above answer is generalized, it would work for all word combinations, see the `elephant` example

Comment: Ah, I see that now. Thank you

Comment: English is subtler than that; the a/an rule is phonetic, not graphemic. Eg. "A useful example"; "An hospital" (not in all English dialects); English is subtler than that; the a/an rule is phonetic, not graphemic. Eg. "a useful example"; "an hour"; "a European"; "an X-ray".

Comment: @rici you are right, I had posted the answer along with the rule to clarify OPs intention